# `tce-load -wi stress` doesn't work?

Tags: linux, stress, tiny-core-linux

I want to install the `stress` command in docker machine, but when I run:

```
tce-load -wi stress
```

It fails:

```
Downloading: stress.tcz
Connecting to repo.tinycorelinux.net (89.22.99.37:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
md5sum: stress.tcz.md5.txt: No such file or directory
Error on stress.tcz
```

But if I install `nano`:

```
docker@daocloud:~$ tce-load -wi nano
nano.tcz.dep OK
Downloading: file.tcz
Connecting to repo.tinycorelinux.net (89.22.99.37:80)
file.tcz             100% |*****************************************|   312k  0:00:00 ETA
file.tcz: OK
Downloading: nano.tcz
Connecting to repo.tinycorelinux.net (89.22.99.37:80)
nano.tcz             100% |*****************************************|   116k  0:00:00 ETA
nano.tcz: OK
docker@daocloud:~$
```

It's successful.

But all of them are in the list of http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tcz_2x.html.

What's wrong and how to install `stress`?

Comment: same problem here, i see package in the list(and it is the right one for my version of core), but `tce-load` does not find it....

Answer (score 1):

Had what sounds like same issue.  The repository urls online all point to version 2 or v3 of tinycore.   New versions of tinycore are v8, so they have different repositories which don't appear to show up in google.

Was able to figure out my version using:

```
version
8.1.1
```

Then when I went to :

```
http://repo.tinycorelinux.net/8.x/x86/tcz/
```

The repository I had problems with had been removed.

This explains what happened.  Solution is to make a new extension.

Making extensions is describe in Tiny Core (p73-77): ['Into The Core'](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/corebook.pdf).

This is very straightforward once you've compiled the app.