# How to install packages on OpenFOAM docker-machine - boot2docker: bash: tce-load: command not found

Tags: boot2docker, openfoam, tiny-core-linux

I'm trying to install some packages on [the OpenFOAM docker-machine image](https://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary-windows.php) which is based on boot2docker. When running the `uname -a` command I get the info:

> Linux default 4.4.111-boot2docker #1 SMP Thu Jan 11 16:25:31 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

In [this page](http://frungy.org/docker/boot2docker-installing-packages) it has been explained that the boot2docker distro is based on the `Tiny Core Linux` distro so to install a package one must:

1. check [the Tiny Core Linux software repository page](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tcz_2x.html)
2. use the command `tce-load -w -i packagename.tcz` to install

I followed these steps to install git. but I get the error:

> bash: tce-load: command not found

I searched and as explained [here](https://github.com/synack/docker-rsync/issues/18) apparently the official repository is offline. There [a list of mirrors](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:mirrors) is provided. But I have no idea how I can install a package from those mirrors!

P.S. Alternatively here [a bizarre answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081170/4999991) by the OP have been upvoted while it is not clear what he/she means by running `boot2docker ssh`

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 10-12-2021:**

Now I have a better understanding of why the `uname -a` returns what it does. Basically, all docker containers share the same kernel as the host Linux OS ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012367/4999991)). To know what is the container's OS, a safe option is the `cat /etc/issue` ([reference](https://serverfault.com/a/805390/352925)). Moreover, it seems like that some of the new "official" OpenFOAM containers are based on Ubuntu, without any admin passwords. So one can just install new packages with `apt`/`apt-get`/...

**new/correct:**

Thanks to [Pawan Ghildiyal from ESI Group](https://www.linkedin.com/in/pawan-ghildiyal-401a2034/) and [Karen Kettle from OpenCFD Limited](https://www.linkedin.com/in/karen-kettle-5a391b16/) I found the correct solution.

It seems like the whole OpenFOAM docker image is based on `CentOS` not `boot2docker` and one can easily install new packages using `yum`! Because the small virtual box interface that enable docker to run is named as boot2docker it returns as `boot2docker` when asked by `uname -a`.
you just need to use the `root` user in docker terminal:

1. run `Docker QuickStart Terminal` (I'm using windows)
2. `docker start of_1712`
3. `docker exec -ti of_1712 /bin/bash`
4. `su -` and then the default password, in this case `fuser2017`!
5. `yum install packageName`

**old/wrong:**

As explained [here](https://blog.pavelsklenar.com/5-useful-docker-tip-and-tricks-on-windows/) it turns out that Docker deprecates the `Boot2Docker` command line in favor of `docker-machine`. So the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081170/4999991) is also depreciated.

**Solution:**

1. Using the command `docker-machine ssh machinename` (in my case `machinename` is `default`) connect to the docker-machine image.
2. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067680/4999991) run the command `version` and look for the package name in the right repository. in my case the version is `8.2.1` and the repository is [`http://repo.tinycorelinux.net/8.x/x86/tcz/`](http://repo.tinycorelinux.net/8.x/x86/tcz/)
3. then run the command `tce-load -w -i packagename.tcz`.

For some reason the official `OpenFOAM_Start` batch file provided by the OpenFOAM team does not work!